# The set of elements that make up the minor of an $n \times n$ matrix of order $k$ is completely determined by the minors $k$ diagonal elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to complete a proof for the following exercise:

> If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix verify that the set of elements that make up the minor $A_{I \times J}:=|A_{i_1 i_2 \dots i_k ,j_1 j_2 \dots j_k}|$ of order $k$ is completely determined by its $k$ diagonal elements.

---

My idea was the following:

Take the list of diagonal elements of minor $A_{I \times J}$ this list is: $a_{i_1 ,j_1},a_{i_2 ,j_2}, \dots a_{i_k ,j_k}$ If there exists some $a_{i_\ell ,j_\ell}$ and $a_{i_h ,j_h}$ such that $\ell<h$ but $i_\ell \geq i_h$ or $j_\ell \geq j_h$ then $A_{I \times J}$ is not a minor. However, if no such $\ell$ and $h$ exists then the series of inequalities $1\leq i_1 < i_2 < \dots < i_k$ and $1\leq j_1 < j_2 < \dots < j_k$ is satisfied and $A_{I \times J}$ is a minor. Thus, the elements that make up the set of minors of order $k$ is completely determined by the diagonal elements of the minor. $\square$

Is this proof actually doing anything or am I just essentially restating what I am trying to prove?

Comment: What is the exercise even trying to say? That $k^2$ elements are somehow determined by only $k$? That is clearly false.

Comment: I think it is trying to say that if we let $\mathbb{K}$ be the set of minors of some $n \times n$ matrix $A$ prove that the inclusion/exclusion of elements in $\mathbb{K}$ is determined only by the diagonal elements of any possible submatrix of $A$.

Comment: Where does this come from?